# Sound stops working after changing default device in Realtek HD Audio Manager

Tags: windows-7, audio, hdmi, realtek-hd-audio

I was messing around in my audio manager EQing  and clicked Set as default device. Then all of a sudden my sound stopped working.

I can see the song playing and everything but nothing comes out the speakers.  I am using Windows 7 with a realtek HD audio manager running HDMI out to TV.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the sound icon located in the system tray, choose **Playback devices**, select the TV as the playback device and set it as default. This should normally get your sound working again.